# PHP: Remove all but the last two element from an associative array

Tags: php, arrays, php-5.5

I have the following string: `"Bikes->Hardtails->XC"`. I'm exploding the array on the `"->"` characters to split the individual words in to elements in an associative array. If the array has more two elements, I'm attempting to remove all array elements prior to the last two elements. So in the following array, I want to remove index `0` and its association, then I will implode.

```
[0] => Bikes, [1] => Hardtails, [2] => XC
```

I have the following code so far which looks good so far. However I'm struggling to finish it.

```
 $cat_path = explode("->",$cat_path);

 if(count($cat_path,1) > 2){

    foreach($cat_path as $path){
        $counter = count($cat_path,1);
        $remove = $counter -2;

    }
  }
```

Is the best solution here to use a nested loop which unsets the unwanted indexes and their associations?

Comment: `$cat_path = array_slice($cat_path, -2);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [array_slice()](http://php.net/array_slice)

```
 if (is_array($cat_path) && count($cat_path) > 2) {
   $cat_path = array_slice($cat_path, -2);
 }
```

Comment: Nice, that simplifies things somewhat. Thanks